# XAML Unable to Read Values From Resx file

Tags: wpf

I have an composite application which has a Shell window and has some modules, each module is loaded on to the shell using MEF (Microsfot Prism). Shell Itself has a resource file default(Resource.resx)  and for other languages(like Resource.ar-SA.resx) too to support Localilzation.

- For Xaml : I had used `x:Static Resource.KeyName`
- In c# Code : I had used `GetString(keyName, culture)` to get the required string.

To support Localization, I have added a line of code which gets the current culture of the system and loads the required Resx File.
For Setting the Current Culture.

```
Resource.Culture = 
    new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);
```

in App.Xaml.cs

All these work Completely fine.

Similarly, each module which is loaded using MEF has Resource files as mentioned above. But in case of Modules, resource Key defined in the Xaml for a specific language file is not working. Its always getting the values from the Default (Resource.Resx) file. But any key used in the code using ResourceManager class works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up keeping all my resources in an "Infrastructure" project so all the resources are loaded from one place, it just made it simpler.

My xaml bindings look like this

Get the refrence to your resx class.

```
xmlns:resources="clr-namespace:Infrastructure.resources;assembly=Infrastructure"
```

now get the text

```
Content="{x:Static resources:Resources.Activity_Regarding}"
```

You might be doing this already but I cant see. You would want to make sure the namespace matches for the resx you want to use. So your modules namespace.